# What is equivalent of $f(t) = -t \sqrt{n} + n\log\left(1+ \frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ where $n$ goes to $ + \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> What is equivalent of $f(t) = -t \sqrt{n} + n\log\left(1+ \frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ where $n$ goes to $ + \infty$?

The answer that I should find is $-\frac{t^2}{2}$

But I didn't understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may apply the Taylor series of $$\log(1+x)=x-x^2/2+x^3/3-...$$ to get 
$$ f(t)=\sqrt n t -\sqrt n t -t^2/2+\frac {t^3}{3\sqrt n}-...$$

As $n\to \infty$ our function looks like $-t^2/2$

Answer (score 2):

By the Taylor's Theorem, $\log(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$ as $x \to 0$. So, as $n\to\infty$,

$$ f(t) = -t\sqrt{n} + n \left( \frac{t}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{t^2}{2n} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{t^3}{n^{3/2}}\right) \right) = -\frac{t^2}{2} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{t^3}{\sqrt{n}}\right). $$

Alternatively, write

$$ f(t) = -\frac{t^2}{2} + \int_{0}^{t} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{n}+x} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

and notice that the integral part converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.